# How to define number columns with CHECK constraints in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, error-handling, database-schema

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'number,
> hofYear number(4) CHECK (hofYear BETWEEN 1901 AND 2155),
> hofSeries VAR' at line 22

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE mospo_HallOfFame( 
    hofdriverId number,
    hofYear number(4) CHECK (hofYear BETWEEN 1901 AND 2155),
    hofSeries VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL CHECK (hofSeries IN ('BritishGT','Formula1','FormulaE','SuperGT')),
```

Comment: You appear to be trying to use *Oracle* syntax on *MySql*. As you have noticed, that won't work; review the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE mospo_HallOfFame( 
  hofdriverId INTEGER, 
  hofYear INTEGER CHECK (hofYear BETWEEN 1901 AND 2155), 
  hofSeries VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL CHECK (hofSeries IN ('BritishGT','Formula1','FormulaE','SuperGT')));
```

This changes the data types to `INTEGER`s and a `VARCHAR`.

Comment: MySQL has a `YEAR` datatype.